# Not specifying the main effect of a term that is part of a tensor product interaction

Tags: nonparametric, interaction, generalized-additive-model, scale-invariance

Say you've got a model 
$$
y = f(X_1,X_2)+\epsilon
$$

and you're OK with linear (or other parametric) functional forms.  Say you think that the effect of $X_1$ on $y$ depends on $X_2$.  The standard wisdom is that one should include the main effect of the interaction to capture the effect of $X_1$ on $y$ when $X_2$ = 0, and to render coefficients invariant to location changes.

I am curious whether this applies to generalized additive models estimated by penalized splines, with interactions represented by tensor products.  Intuitively, it seems like it would NOT apply.

WRT the first issue, the tensor product smooth estimates the "height" of a surface defined by two variables, along a grid.  Thus you've always got a function for one variable at a fixed value of the other.  If you had a univariate smooth along with it, you'd have to simply add the two, at a cost of degrees of freedom (which would get penalized/reduced).

WRT the second issue, [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4124523) by Simon Wood lays out how the tensor products implemented in `gam` are scale invariant.

Is this a reasonable interpretation?  If I wanted to estimate the model above nonparametrically, is it unreasonable to leave out smooth functions of $X_1$ and $X_2$, and simply model $X_1 \otimes X_2$.

If yes, how would you quickly and imply explain why to an audience that isn't used to GAMs?